# Adding popup info in openlayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

Im using this code to load a kml file over the map which in this case Im using OpenStreetMap.
I want to know how can I add a popup when clicking on the kml(road) so that it shows some information about it.

```
var line_1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.GML(
    'Line - 1', 
    "lines/line_1.kml",
    {
        visibility: true,
        format: OpenLayers.Format.KML,
        style: 
        {
            strokeWidth: 4, 
            strokeColor: "#ff0000", 
            strokeOpacity: 1
        },
        projection: map.displayProjection
    }
);
```

Comment: I want to do something like: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/dynamic-text-layer.html and http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-openpopup.html but I simply dont know how to put the sode together... :/

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? Any comments?

Answer (score 4):

A GML layer is really a Vector layer instantiated with GML data. So you can look into how Vector layers should be used for opening popups. Your example is already doing that.

They use a Select Control and opens the popup when a feature is selected:

```
selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(polygonLayer,
            {onSelect: onFeatureSelect, onUnselect: onFeatureUnselect});
```

Where `polygonLayer` in your case would be `line_1` instead.

Create a method `onFeatureSelect` where you open a popup:

```
        function onFeatureSelect(feature) {
        selectedFeature = feature;
        popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken", 
                                 feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                                 null,
                                 "<div style='font-size:.8em'>Feature: " + feature.id +"<br>Area: " + feature.geometry.getArea()+"</div>",
                                 null, true, onPopupClose);
        feature.popup = popup;
        map.addPopup(popup);
    }
```

Where `map` is your map object.

Try it out and comment on your progress or questions.

Comment: Please guide me this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470470/show-pop-up-box-on-google-map-sometime-it-didnt-show-it